# zcat/gzcat works in linux, not on osx. general linux/osx compatibility

Tags: linux, mac-osx, bash

First the specific problem:
In linux, I use zcat to list a .zip file. In osx, zcat seems to automatically append .Z to the file name. Various people suggest replacing zcat with gzcat; however, gzcat complains that the file is not in gzip format!

'file ' shows this:
...Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract

So neither zcat or gzcat will work in osx, what can I do?

I have a medium sized script in in bash which uses, zcat/gzcat, sed awk and other basic utilities to process a number of files. I'd like to duplicate that environment on my osx laptop so I can work offline. Any general suggestions how I can avoid such pain? I expect this is a fairly routine workflow so must have been sorted out by others.

Comment: If it's Zip archive data, it's **not** in gzip format!

Comment: @MichaelHampton I can zcat on linux fine. Neither zcat nor gzcat works on osx. So how can I resolve this? Is there another set of utilities I can install which will work both on linux as well as osx? These scripts are my own so I can change them (although I'd like to keep them simple). I control both linux/osx environments as well so I can do simple installs on both as well.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's routine. I generally use `zip` to deal with zip files, not `gzip`.

Answer (score 151):

You are right. It's annoying behavior.

```
$ zcat foo.txt.gz 
zcat: can't stat: foo.txt.gz (foo.txt.gz.Z): No such file or directory
```

Try this:

```
$ zcat < foo.txt.gz 
asdfadsf
```

Comment: This works ok on OS X.

Comment: Apparently my answer is wrong. Linux `zcat` will read `.zip` and `.Z` files. The issue here isn't one of stdin vs. named file, it's that the Linux maintainers of the programs modified `gzcat` to read a large number of unrelated file types.

Comment: How would we pipe this to another process?

Comment: Use `|` to pipe to another process: `cat < foo.txt.gz | wc`

Comment: This will fix your issue, at least on OSX

Comment: `cat < foo.txt.gz | wc` counts the number of lines in the compressed file, not in the uncompressed file.

Comment: If you only ever call `zcat` with the file argument (no other argument), you can fix it by adding the following to `~/.bashrc`: `function zcat { command zcat < "$1" }`

Answer (score 37):

I know this is an old question.
However, I found a solution from an even older [github thread](https://github.com/dalibo/pgbadger/issues/70).

You can simply use `gunzip -c` that works similar to `zcat` without the errors on Mac OS X.

```
$ gunzip -c 20150707_backup.sql.gz | mysql -u mysql_user -p
```

Comment: `gzip` might work instead of `gunzip` too.

Answer (score 18):

You can install GNU utils for Mac OS X, e.g., using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (run `brew install coreutils gnu-sed`, which installs `gzcat` et al. and `gsed`). This will provide you with the GNU implementation of each command.

Then, to make your life easier, make a variable for each command (e.g. `sed=gsed`, and use `$sed` subsequently), or simply alias them (e.g. `alias sed=gsed`) in any script you write. I've written a Gist on this for your convenience: [gnu-tools-for-mac.sh](https://gist.github.com/bittner/5436f3dc011d43ab7551). Put (or include) this code on top of your scripts.

Use the GNU implementation for both compressing and extracting the archives. I'd say you can't mix the uses of the OS X and GNU implementation.

Comment: You can alternatively add `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin` to your `PATH`, which will make them available without the `g` prefix.

Answer (score 15):

I just gave this a try and found something very interesting! For `gz` files, we are expected to run `gzcat` on Mac OS.

### Solution 1

- Use `gzcat /path/to/file.gz` and it should work.
- Using `zcat /path/to/file.gz` will give you an error.

### Solution 2

- Pipe in the file to `zcat` and it will work.
- For example, `cat /path/to/file.gz | zcat` will work.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
zcat filename.gz | grep "hello"
```

Use

```
gunzip -c filename.gz | grep "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Mac OS X version of `gzip(1)` [doesn't support reading zip files](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/gunzip.1.html). From the man page:

> This version of **gzip** is also capable of decompressing files compressed using `compress(1)` or `bzip2(1)`.

[But the Linux (GNU) version does](http://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/gzip.html).

> `gunzip` can currently decompress files created by `gzip`, `zip`, `compress`, `compress -H` or `pack`.

Third parties have packaged GNU gzip for Mac OS X; you can find these from a web search. That is probably the path of least resistance.

Comment: Searching the web and installing new software is *never* the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I had the same issue when executing a `bash`-script, `bash somescript.sh`, which executed a for-loop with `gzcat` inside it. But trying these things *inside* the `somescript.sh`-script ...:

1. `zcat < file.txt.gz`
2. I had installed `brew install coreutils` already, but nonetheless, re-installed: `brew reinstall coreutils`
3. `gunzip -c file.txt.gz`

... amounted to nothing...

But I also used a reference to a directory:

`SOMEDIR="~/DIR1/DIR2/DATA"`

Which is interpreted as `~/DIR1/DIR2/DATA` and apparently doesn't work within the `bash`-script within `macOS`. This worked:

`SOMEDIR="${HOME}/DIR1/DIR2/DATA"`

Which is interpreted as `/Users/someuser/DIR1/DIR2/DATA`. I don't know why - I'm not an expert macOS-BASH-techie - but it worked in conjunction with my original code ...

`gzcat file.txt.gz | awk '{ print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6 }' > ${SOMEDIR}/new.file.txt`.

... *within* my `somescript.sh`-script.

Maybe it's useful to someone.

Best,

Sander

Answer (score 0):

As reported in https://stackoverflow.com/a/296725/4725074

Using `gzcat` instead of `zcat` solved my issue.